# RegEx validation for Treelist in Sitecore?

Tags: regex, sitecore

In Sitecore when I add items to my Treelist I would like the treelist to only allow no items or 2 - 3 items.

In the template of the item I can set RegEx in the validation field to achieve this.

I've found this RegEx [here](http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2010/11/Validate-a-Sitecore-Checklist-Multilist-Treelist-or-TreelistEx-Field.aspx):  ^.{0,116}$

This regex allows 0-3 items. But how could I not allow 1?

*Update: Edited my first question to be more exact into my problem. Sorry..*

Comment: The example you reference is for a "validation" field on a Sitecore Listbox.  How are you attempting to use it in a Treelist?

Comment: Found this link http://bit.ly/jdcUVT but how could I set to not allow 1 in this regex ^.{0,116}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the answer to my question.

This would validate correctly:

```
^(.{0}|.{77,116})$
```

If anyone has a better answer, please submit. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6):

```
(...{2,3})?
```

Make your expression match 2 or 3 items and make the whole expression optional using `?`.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. See my updated question for better understanding in my problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like: A(|foo{2,3})B which matches AB, AfoofooB, and AfoofoofooB.

However, you really should consider that perhaps not using regex for counting the number of matches would generally be better.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is "yes" (see deceze's answer).  But, you are adding to a list, and adding nothing to the list is a noop (unless you are adding a null entry?).  You could simply look for 2 or 3 (...{2,3}).

This is why it's always good to supply context with your question, that is when you get the best answers.

This example will add all the lines that match your pattern to the list when there are 2 or 3 matches.

```
        var list = new List<Match>();
        var textlines = @"
This is a test
*}|{*
*}|{**}|{*
*}|{**}|{**}|{*
*}|{**}|{**}|{**}|{**}|{**}|{*
";

        var pattern = @"^(\*\}\|\{\*){2,3}$";
        var mx = Regex.Matches(textlines, pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline);

        foreach (Match m in mx)
            list.Add(m);
```

However, the sample data is contrived based upon your pattern.  Is this really how your data looks?  Or could it be you are looking for something more like...

```
        var list = new List<Match>();
        var textlines = @"
This is a test
*}|{*
*}|{*blah blah blah*}|{*
*}|{*blah blah blah*}|{*blah blah blah*}|{*
*}|{*blah blah blah*}|{*blah blah blah*}|{*blah blah blah*}|{*blah blah blah*}|{*blah blah blah*}|{*
";

        var pattern = @"^([^*]*\*\}\|\{\*){2,3}$"; //notice the change to the pattern
        var mx = Regex.Matches(textlines, pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline);

        foreach (Match m in mx)
            list.Add(m);
```

Regardless, I hope this helps you along in some way.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. See my updated question for better understanding in my problem. :)